# How can webpack terser avoid mangling jQuery methods?

Tags: webpack, terser

When using webpack 5 with Terser mangle options. We must keep mangling enabled in production for business reasons on this project.

```
 optimization: {
            minimize: true,
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    parallel: true,
                    terserOptions: {
                        toplevel: true,
                        mangle: {
                            properties: {
                                keep_quoted: true,
                                debug: true,
                            },                       
                        },
                    }
                }),
       ]
}
```

I'm leaving the `debug:true` option for the ease of exemplifying the issue.

Having jQuery loaded externally (think Shopify or other env where we access jQuery from the window context).

```js
// $ is global, via webpack externs 
this.jTitle = $('title').first();
```

Becomes

```js
// $ is global, via webpack externs 
this._$jTitle$_=$("title")._$first$_()
```

I want it to become

```js
// $ is global, via webpack externs 
this._$jTitle$_=$("title").first()
```

This happens in all the codebase, breaking the bundle, and I cannot create a functioning bundle.

Update:

A repo that exemplifies the issue is here (branch name is important, beware! example-import-problem is the branch that has the issue): https://github.com/vladnicula/terser-for-the-win/tree/example-import-problem

[image: Demo problem]

Comment: Did you defined jquery as external? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: Yes. Defining as external does not change this behaviour. I tried with both `import $ from 'jquery'`  AND without importing it and get the same result.

Comment: It's very strange. It has something to do with the webpack system, as importing the entire bundle from webpack in https://try.terser.org/ produces the error, while importing parts of the webpack bundle, specifically one module that has the `first` method bug does not produce this error

Comment: can you prepare a small repo which I will able to play with?

Comment: I'll start today, will post the repo link when done in the question content

Comment: It works properly in your repo, I can see `extrected with jQuery:  Webpack Terser Externals` in the console

Comment: I've tried to remove the terser config, it still works as expected

Comment: @felixmosh did you try the master branch or the `example-import-problem`? I just checked on `example-import-problem` and have the issue.

Comment: added screenshot with problem happening on example repo

Comment: I've tested the master branch :)

Comment: I've made a PR for your repo, Just removed the optimisation block, it now uses the default params.

Comment: There is a reason that you need to specify the Terser config?

Comment: Yes. The code is for a product that is being actively cloned by competition and mangled code reduces the speed with which competitors copy the code. It's a hard requirement. We need to make the code harder to debug and understand.

Comment: But I appreciate the effort, thank you @felixmosh